# sudo apt-get crashed during hbase installation

Tags: installation, java, hadoop

I had problem regarding hbase installation and end up in a buggy "sudo apt-get" now. It is telling me JAVA_HOME is not set while it is.

```
jalal@mona:~$ sudo apt-get -f install 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
hadoop-hbase
The following NEW packages will be installed:
hadoop-hbase
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 18 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/30.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 34.7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Selecting previously unselected package hadoop-hbase.
(Reading database ... 264105 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking hadoop-hbase (from .../hadoop-hbase_0.90.6+84.89-1~maverick-    cdh3_all.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up hadoop-hbase (0.90.6+84.89-1~maverick-cdh3) ...
Setting up hadoop-hbase-master (0.90.6+84.89-1~maverick-cdh3) ...
+======================================================================+
|      Error: JAVA_HOME is not set and Java could not be found         |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Please download the latest Sun JDK from the Sun Java web site        |
|       > http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/ <                      |
|                                                                      |
| HBase requires Java 1.6 or later.                                    |
| NOTE: This script will find Sun Java whether you install using the   |
|       binary or the RPM based installer.                             |
+======================================================================+
invoke-rc.d: initscript hadoop-hbase-master, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing hadoop-hbase-master (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up hadoop-hbase-regionserver (0.90.6+84.89-1~maverick-cdh3) ...
+======================================================================+
|      Error: JAVA_HOME is not set and Java could not be found         |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Please download the latest Sun JDK from the Sun Java web site        |
|       > http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/ <                      |
|                                                                      |
| HBase requires Java 1.6 or later.                                    |
| NOTE: This script will find Sun Java whether you install using the   |
|       binary or the RPM based installer.                             |
+======================================================================+
invoke-rc.d: initscript hadoop-hbase-regionserver, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing hadoop-hbase-regionserver (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up hadoop-hbase-rest (0.90.6+84.89-1~maverick-cdh3) ...
+======================================================================+
|      Error: JAVA_HOME is not set and Java could not be found         |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Please download the latest Sun JDK from the Sun Java web site        |
|       > http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/ <                      |
|                                                                      |
| HBase requires Java 1.6 or later.                                    |
| NOTE: This script will find Sun Java whether you install using the   |
|       binary or the RPM based installer.                             |
+======================================================================+
invoke-rc.d: initscript hadoop-hbase-rest, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing hadoop-hbase-rest (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up hadoop-hbase-thrift (0.90.6+84.89-1~maverick-cdh3) ...
+======================================================================+
|      Error: JAVA_HOME is not set and Java could not be found         |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Please download the latest Sun JDK from the Sun Java web site        |
|       > http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/ <                      |
|                                                                      |
| HBase requires Java 1.6 or later.                                    |
| NOTE: This script will find Sun Java whether you install using the   |
|       binary or the RPM based installer.                             |
+======================================================================+
invoke-rc.d: initscript hadoop-hbase-thrift, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing hadoop-hbase-thrift (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Errors were encountered while processing:
hadoop-hbase-master
hadoop-hbase-regionserver
hadoop-hbase-rest
hadoop-hbase-thrift
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

According to

```
echo $(readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:bin/java::")
```

my JAVA_HOME is

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/
```

and here's echoing it:

```
jalal@mona:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/
```

Please let me know how I can fix my `sudo apt-get install` in the very first place and then how is it possible to install hbase using `sudo apt-get install`?

by adding 
    `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre \` 
using `sudo nano  /usr/lib/hbase/bin/hbase-config.sh`
to :

```
for candidate in \  
   /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun \  
   /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-sun-1.6.0.*/jre \  
   /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-sun-1.6.0.* \  
   /usr/lib/j2sdk1.6-sun \  
   /usr/java/jdk1.6* \  
   /usr/java/jre1.6* \  
   /Library/Java/Home ; do  
if [ -e $candidate/bin/java ]; then  
    export JAVA_HOME=$candidate  
    break  
 fi  
done
```

I stopped receiving `JAVA_HOME not found` error.

However now I have this error after `sudo apt-get install -f`:

```
pam_mount(spawn.c:128): error setting uid to 0
```

Any fix to my `sudo apt-get install`?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `sudo` command, it acts like you did `su`. Difference is that `sudo` executes only one given command then immediatly exits. But all the consequences of changing user are present. That means, if you did not setup environment variables for `root` user, they will be empty. You can check this running:

```
user@host:~$ su
Password:
root@host:/home/user$ echo $JAVA_HOME

root@host:/home/user$
```

You can setup variables for `root` just like you did for `user`. But the more convenient way is to setup them in `/etc/environment` file

```
$ cat /etc/environment
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/default-java"
_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true"
```